# SQL Server Availability Groups and different collations

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, alwayson

I have a unique challenge and I wanted to get other's opinions on this.
I have a vendor database that is currently on SQL Server 2008 R2 and I need to migrate it off that server, for obvious reasons.

I would like to move it to my SQL Server 2016 AlwaysON AG, and the vendor supports AG configurations as well as SQL Server 2016.

The issue is that the Vendor's database is in a different collation than the default SQL Server collation and they need the collation of the master, tempdb and the user database to match.

I wanted to get your thoughts on installing a named instance on the two servers that host the current AG with the vendor specified collation and creating a new AG for that named instance.

I need to have this database in a HR solution and I do not want to stand up two new servers just to host this one database.

Another question with the AG on the same box, will I be able to use the default port that the default instance and existing listener is using?

Answer (score 0):

1. Install  a new  named instance with vendor collation
2. use a different port for AG default 5022
3. Use different  TCP port for  New instance ( Not default 1433)